# Switch statement C# using data from MYSQL databse

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, switch-statement

OK, so I have a column in MYSQL data base, the column called `specie` in there I have dog,cat,and rabbit.
I then have a drop down list that is populated with the data from `specie`. I need a `switch statement` that will display a `Label` for each pet selected.
e.g. if user selects rabbit, the rabbit cost £00.00

**here is my code for the drop down list**

```
 public partial class _Default : Page
{

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    MySqlConnection cs = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER= 000.000.00.000;username=*****;password=*****; Initial Catalog = mydb");
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pets", cs);
        cs.Open();
        MySqlDataReader ddl = cd.ExecuteReader();
        DdPetPist.DataSource = ddl;
        DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
        DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
        DdPetPist.DataBind();
        cs.Close();
        cs.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: can i make a switch statement using the data from mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have the cost of each animal stored in the database as well.
If so, here is how I would do this:

1. Populate the dropdown list like you currently do.
2. In .NET you can specify AutoPostBack="true" and onSelectedIndexChanged="someMethod". The former will post back to the server on dropdown change and the latter will call "someMethod".
3. This "someMethod" can then look up the cost in the database for the species selected, and populate the label.

Makes sense?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I do not have the value in the data base, I shall make a row called Cost now and try you answer. thank you

Comment: If this answer works for you, please accept it as the correct answer and/or upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: I will do am trying it now

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, ok I have made it autopostback and made a selectmethord called 'ChosenAnimal', also made a column in my table called 'PetMinDonation' how would I write a statement to look up the species?

Comment: What do you mean? SQL statement?

Comment: I am not to sure, I thought I would need a switch/case statment